# How to Find and delete File Older than 3 years without scaning on modified date?

Tags: linux, files, date, rm, images

I have 1 folder with image `.jpg` file, and I'm sure that folder image older than 5 years.

Now I must delete image older than 3 year.

I know i can find it with this

```
find /path/to/files* -mtime +1095 -exec rm {} \;
```

or

```
find /path/to/files* -mtime +1095 -delete;
```

But Nothing Happen.

My issue is that I think date modified file has been change because I have Resync it to other server when down.

How can I delete that file, without scaning on modified date?

I'm Very Appreciate your answer.

Thanks

Comment: Which filesystem?

Comment: First check whether those files are listing or not by replacing 'rf' with 'ls'. If they were older than 3 years then you will get all those files.

Comment: @HaukeLaging Debian 8

Comment: @NaushadAhmad  "find /path/to/files* -mtime +1095 -exec ls {} \;"  is what you mean? the result "bash: /usr/bin/find: Argument list too long
" anything wrong?

Comment: Ok, see my answer, hope it will resolve.

Comment: Seriously, your **fileystem** is Debian 8?

Answer (score 2):

If the EXIF tags in the images are correct, you can use exiftool to change the file modification date to the one given by the tags, and then use find to delete the old ones.

Comment: OK I will Try it, but I'm still dont have experience with EXIF. I will googling for it.

Answer (score 0):

Browse to the current directory where all those old files are located:

```
cd /path/to/the/directory
```

Check if you can see all those old files:

```
ls
```

Now run this command

```
find . -mtime +1095 -exec rm -Rf -- {} \;
```

Done!!!

Comment: hi I have try your answer, ls command can list it, but I must stop it because to huge. After du -sh that file size is 17 Gb and after running your advice, nothing happen. and check again SiZe still 17 GB.

Comment: ok try this again and show me the output find . -mtime +1095 -exec rm -rf {} \;

Comment: Sir, on my question, i have try this "find . -mtime +1095 -exec rm -rf {} \;"  and nothing happen. The issue is, Modified date on file has been changed after I have Resync from old Server to New Server. Now I Think I must Find and Delete the Old File not with file Modified Date. because it will search nothing older then 3 years. I hope you know what I mean. Any Idea?

Comment: I understand it but you already mentioned in your previous comment that while listing using ls instead of rm, you got Argument list too long. That means there are files available which are of more than 3 yrs old. So, to resolve it I asked you to use find . (dot) after browsing to that directory. without using -- as I said in comment. So, please try once more this command--   find . -mtime +1095 -exec rm -rf {} \; (make sure your are in that directory)

Comment: Hi Sir, I'm sure, and I have try once again on my directory, I try it "find . -mtime +1095 -exec rm -Rf -- {} \;" and after enter, it nothing happen. if I can upload an image I will Upload it for you. Thanks for helping me. But Any Idea again? Hans Martin gave me answer must using EXIF , but I dont know how to use it.

Comment: I told you not to use -- and rf not Rf. And in case, if this one also not work then need to find some other solution.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75548/discussion-between-uchsun-and-naushad-ahmad).